# How to round the result of a computation to n decimal places in Java

Tags: java

I can see that there are hundreds of posts on the subject of rounding decimal places.  However, I have searched high and low and cannot seem to find a previous instance that matches my problem.
I am pretty new to java.

I am trying to calculate the slope of a line, assign it to a variable and have the contents of that variable be formatted to 4 decimal places.

I have tried DecimalFormat (appears to return a string, I need a numerical value that can be used in another stage of calculations)
I have tried BigDecimal (cannot seem to figure out how to construct it and setScale).
Below is my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BigDecimal slope1, slope2, slope3;

        slope1 = new BigDecimal((8 - 8) / (20 - 5));
        slope2 = new BigDecimal((9 - 8) / (22 - 5));
        slope3 = new BigDecimal((9 - 8) / (22 - 20));
        slope1 = slope1.setScale(4);
        slope2 = slope1.setScale(4);
        slope3 = slope1.setScale(4);
        System.out.println(slope1);
        System.out.println(slope2);
        System.out.println(slope3);



    }


}
```

The resulting output is:

```
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
```

How to I construct the big data object, set it's scale, and do the calculation in a way that will give the real result of the calculation to 4 decimal places and not 0.0000?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been messing with this for hours.

Comment: the computation is done before the data reaches the bigdecimal. basically you are doing `slope3 = new BigDecimal(0);`

Comment: You're never going to get anything other than zero out of slope1 - because the numerator (8 - 8) is zero, as for the others - as mentioned you need to coerce the ratio into a double first.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two problems here.

The first is that you are using integer arithmetic in the constructor of your `BigDecimal`s.
You can fix this by casting the value to **double**.

Your second problem is that you are setting the scale of `slope1` three times, and ignoring the values of `slope2` and `slope3` here:

```
slope1 = slope1.setScale(4);
slope2 = slope1.setScale(4);  // should be slope2
slope3 = slope1.setScale(4);  // should be slope3
```

However, when you fix this, you'll get an `ArithmeticException` when you try to calculate `slope2`. Whenever you use `scale()` to round a number, you need to specify a `RoundingMode` so that it knows *how* you want to round.

Try this:

```
    slope1 = new BigDecimal((double) (8 - 8) / (20 - 5));
    slope2 = new BigDecimal((double) (9 - 8) / (22 - 5));
    slope3 = new BigDecimal((double) (9 - 8) / (22 - 20));
    slope1 = slope1.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    slope2 = slope2.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    slope3 = slope3.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(slope1); // 0.0000
    System.out.println(slope2); // 0.0588
    System.out.println(slope3); // 0.5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer arithmetic is all whole numbers.

```
    slope1 = new BigDecimal((8d - 8d) / (20d - 5d));
    slope2 = new BigDecimal((9d - 8d) / (22d - 5d));
    slope3 = new BigDecimal((9d - 8d) / (22d - 20d));
```

To just make your code work, append d for double. Basically what's happening is all your numbers are considered integers, and performing integer map does such magic as 9 / 8 evaluates to 1. Other alternatives include hard-casting with decimals or casting the combined values to double.

```
    slope2 = new BigDecimal((9.0 - 8.0) / (22.0 - 5.0));
```

or

```
    slope2 = new BigDecimal((double) (9 - 8) / (double) (22 - 5));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me.  I added the changes you recommended and what was recommended in another comment below.  It looks like it's close to working but now I'm getting an error "RoundingMode cannot be resolved to a variable"  I had tried using RoundingMode earlier and ran into the same problem so went away from it.  I have the import statement import java.math.BigDecimal; included in my code (not shown in my earlier example) above the class declaration.

Comment: Seems I've got it working now.  I managed to do it without invoking Big Decimal.  Your clue to add double type cast into the formula was the breakthrough.  Thanks again very much for your suggestion.

    double slope1 = ((double)(p2.y - p1.y) / (double)(p2.x - p1.x));

    double slope2 = ((double)(p1.y - p.y)  / (double)(p1.x - p.x));

    double slope3 = ((double)(p2.y - p.y)  / (double)(p2.x - p.x));

Answer (score 0):

What is really the problem here is **int arithmetic**:

`(9 - 8) / (20 - 5)` is equal to `1 / 15` which in int arithmetic is equal to `0`.

To get the right result you have to enforce double arithmetic by making at least one of the numbers `double`:

`((double)(9 - 8) / (20 - 5))` or `((9.0 - 8) / (20 - 5))`

Answer (score 0):

change
 `slope1 = new BigDecimal((8 - 8) / (20 - 5));` 
to
 `slope1 = new BigDecimal(((double)8 - 8) / ((double)20 - 5));`